# npm peerDependencies React : can't install any packages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, semantic-ui, draftjs

I'm building new React App to learn and play with `Draft-js`, RichStyle Text Editor.
I used `create-react-app` to initialize my React application. It's working, and very easy to use.

Now, I tried to add `semantic-ui-react`, which is React version of SemanticUI lib.

Aaaaannd fail.

> npm install semantic-ui-react --save

[image]

As you can see, same effect for draft-js.
My issue is that normally there's no problem to use draft-js & semantic-ui-react with React 15.4.2. I use this stack in professional env.
Is there something I'm missing with npm ? Is `create-react-app` can stop this install ?

Now, I can't install any packages. This error shows up everytime. But, I cant still `npm start` for my local web server. I also tried `npm cache clean`

Is my very simple package.json

[image]

Thanks again for you help.

***Solution*** : Just update NPM and everything working.

***Edit*** : My App folder :

[image]

And my npm & node version

[image]

Comment: run `npm --version` and `node --version` in your terminal and post the results here please

Comment: Just did it. Thanks for your time

Comment: Yeah npm 1.4.9 is really old. Do `npm install npm@latest -g`

Comment: and make sure create-react-app is up-to-date as well

Comment: Update npm and everything is working great. Thanks Chase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have old npm or node versions, you can't start the project with this versions... you can upgrade npm and node programs.
if you are using brew on OSX then you can use following commands to upgrade them.

```
brew update
brew upgrade node
npm install -g npm
```

Comment: And you right. My npm was outdated ... It's woking now. thanks you.

Comment: If you could accept my answer I would really appreciate it :)